# Is it possible to profile a SQLite SQL query?

Tags: sql, c, sqlite

I know how long a query takes. I want to know how long each part of the query takes so that maybe I can cache certain parts to improve performance. The query however is decently complicated. Here is the output of explain:

```
[2,0,0,SCAN TABLE M]
[3,0,0,SCAN TABLE M]
[1,0,0,COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 3 (UNION ALL)]
[5,0,0,SCAN TABLE E]
[6,0,0,SCAN TABLE E]
[4,0,0,COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 5 AND 6 (UNION ALL)]
[8,0,0,SCAN TABLE P]
[9,0,0,SCAN TABLE P]
[7,0,0,COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 8 AND 9 (UNION ALL)]
[0,0,0,SCAN SUBQUERY 1 AS m]
[0,0,0,EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 10]
[0,0,0,EXECUTE LIST SUBQUERY 10]
[0,1,1,SEARCH SUBQUERY 4 AS e USING AUTOMATIC COVERING INDEX (e=?)]
[0,2,2,SCAN SUBQUERY 7 AS p]
[0,0,0,USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY]
[0,0,0,USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY]
```

Is there any way to find out how long each of those steps take?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199790/is-there-a-tool-to-profile-sqlite-queries

Answer (score 2):

You can get overall statistics for the statement's execution with [sqlite3_stmt_status](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt_status.html), but there are no finer-grained statistics.

The steps shown by `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` are not actually separate; the execution of the various operations typically is nested and interleaved.

Read [Query Planning](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html), [The Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html), [The Next-Generation Query Planner](http://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner-ng.html), and [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).
With that information, you usually can estimate how efficient your (sub)queries are.