# Trace SQLite queries in C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, trace

I am working on an application in which we have recently upgraded the SQLite .NET interop from a several years old version to the newest version available. After performing the upgrade I have noticed that several queries are not returning the same results as they did previously and I suspect the .NET wrapper of being the cause of the problem.

If the problem occurred in SQL Server, I would have started the profiler to see which queries were being generated, but for SQLite no such profiler exists.

Is there any way to get a trace of which queries are being executed against an SQLite database (And if possible, is there a way to do it in .NET/C# also) ?

Comment: Are you using an ORM or querying the db directly?

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199790/is-there-a-tool-to-profile-sqlite-queries

Comment: I am querying the database directly, without the use of any ORM.

Comment: The link at  stackoverflow.com/questions/3199790/ describes a method for injecting your own dll between your application and the SQLite dll. Unfortunately this will only work for native code, not .NET code, as the query I am interested in examining is the query generated by the .NET interop.